# Reloading of Editor in Eclipse plugin development is not showing workbench status bar

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have a requirement to close/open an Editor.
To open an Editor I am using page.closeEditor(..) and to open it again I am using page.openEditor(...) but page is not loading workbench status bar.
Please provide your input.

```java
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
final int MATCH_BOTH = IWorkbenchPage.MATCH_INPUT | IWorkbenchPage.MATCH_ID;
part=page.openEditor(input, input.getEditorid(), true, MATCH_BOTH);
part = page.getActiveEditor();
page.closeEditor(part, true);
part = page.openEditor(input,"com.editors.OnlyJavaEditor", true, MATCH_BOTH);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'workbench status bar'?

Comment: Workbench status bar is the bar which shows on downside of Eclipse and displays information about line no,file properties like writable of an opened file in Editor.

Comment: The editor status line depends on which editor you are opening. Some use it, some don't. So which editor are you opening?

Comment: I am opening Java editor.If i open it directly like "open" context menu ,its working perfectly but as soon as i close and reopen it programmaticly,Editor status disappears.For more information,If i again open editor with context menu,status bar appears for previous editor also.

Comment: IWorkbenchWindow window=PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
  IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
final int MATCH_BOTH = IWorkbenchPage.MATCH_INPUT | IWorkbenchPage.MATCH_ID;
   part=page.openEditor(input, input.getEditorid(), true, MATCH_BOTH);
part = page.getActiveEditor();
page.closeEditor(part, true);
part=page.openEditor(input, input.getEditorid(), true, MATCH_BOTH);

Comment: Edit your question and put the code there.

Comment: Yes i did that..Please check it

Comment: Why are you doing such a strange operation?

Comment: I want to open the same file  again in different editor thats why i need to do it

Comment: But this code doesn't do that. It opens the same editor twice which makes very little sense.

Comment: I edited the code as its opening in different Editor.But let me know if there is any other way to do same logic.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To open a specific editor on a file you just need to do:

```java
IWorkbenchPage page = ... get workbench page ...

IFile file = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(..path of file...);
// or some other way of getting an IFile

IEditorInput input = new FileEditorInput(file);

final int MATCH_BOTH = IWorkbenchPage.MATCH_INPUT | IWorkbenchPage.MATCH_ID;

IEditorPart part = page.openEditor(input, "com.editors.OnlyJavaEditor", true, MATCH_BOTH);
```

Comment: Thanks but this will open two Editor with same file but i want to close previous opened Editor and open other Editor.